# Difference between netTcpContextBinding and netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, binding

What is the difference between netTcpContextBinding and netTcpBinding in WCF? When/Why should I pick one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NetTcpContextBinding (and the other *Context* bindings) includes an extra channel in the stack; ContextBindingElement, which is typically used when exposing workflows as services (to help establish and maintain a "session" that correlates on (ex.) a header).

--larsw